# make dynamic return all action of controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have found following code to get all action from controller name.

```
Type t = typeof(YourControllerType);
MethodInfo[] mi = t.GetMethods();
foreach (MethodInfo m in mi)
{
    if (m.IsPublic)
        if (typeof(ActionResult).IsAssignableFrom(m.ReturnParameter.ParameterType))
            methods = m.Name + Environment.NewLine + methods;
}
```

I want to make following code dynamic as function by passing controller name as follows:

```
 public string get_all_action(type ob)
        {
            string methods = "";
            Type t = typeof(ob);
            MethodInfo[] mi = t.GetMethods();

            foreach (MethodInfo m in mi)
            {
                if (m.IsPublic)
                    if (typeof(ActionResult).IsAssignableFrom(m.ReturnParameter.ParameterType))
                        methods = m.Name + Environment.NewLine + methods;
            }

            return methods;
        }
```

But I am confuse what type of parameter should passed to the function at definition and while calling the function.
I have following code to get all controller and pass controller name to get_all_action().

```
var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var controllerTypes = from d in asm.GetExportedTypes() where typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(d) select d;
            foreach(var val in controllerTypes)
            {                
               string actionname = get_all_action(val.Name);


            }
```

Here, val.Name is in string type therefore it throws exception:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `get_all_action` method is expecting to receive a Type as the input parameter, whereas you're attempting to call it with a String (i.e. the Type name) as the input parameter.

The line here:

```
string actionname = get_all_action(val.Name);
```

should instead be:

```
string actionname = get_all_action(val);
```

And the first few lines of your `get_all_action` method should be changed to be:

```
public string get_all_action(Type controllerType)
{
    string methods = "";
    MethodInfo[] mi = controllerType.GetMethods();
```

Comment: I think it's enough with `get_all_action(val)`.

Comment: @Mario, thanks - was being too defensive in my code! (edited with update)